# Merge files with similar name in to one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of files stored in directory such as

```
filenames=[
        abc_1.txt
        abc_2.txt
        abc_3.txt

        bcd_1.txt
        bcd_2.txt
        bcd_3.txt
       ]

pattern=[abc]
```

I want to read multiple txt files into one dataframe such  that all files starting with abc will be in one dataframe then all all filename starting with bcd etc.

My code:

```
filenames = os.listdir(file_path)
expnames=[]
for files in filenames:
     expnames.append(files.rsplit('_',1)[0])

##   expnames=[abc, bcd]

 dfs = []
 for exp in expnames:
      for files in filenames:
          if files.startswith(exp):
               dfs.append(pd.read_csv(file_path+files,sep=',',header=None))
  big_frame = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

My output contain duplicate rows due to multiple for loops

Output:
[image]

Can someone help wih this?

Comment: Do you want all of the `abc` files to be in their own dataframe and all of the `bcd` files to be in a separate dataframe?

Comment: The same dataframe could be overwritten.

Comment: What is the purpose if the dataframe can be overwritten? How do you intend to store these? Does my answer below address your question?

Comment: I will store the output in dataframe and write to csv individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will store your desired outputs in a list of dataframes called `list_of_dfs` and then create a MultiIndex dataframe `final` from them with the file prefixes (e.g. `['abc','bcd']`) as the keys for the outermost index level:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

filenames = os.listdir(file_path)

prefixes = list(set(i.split('_')[0] for i in filenames))

list_of_dfs = [pd.concat([pd.read_csv(os.path.join(file_path, file), header=None) for file in filenames if file.startswith(prefix)], ignore_index=True) for prefix in prefixes]

final = pd.concat(list_of_dfs, keys=prefixes)
```

Comment: Can you show me how to store the output as a dataframe and not as a list? Thanks.

Comment: See the last line of my answer, it passes the list of dataframes to `pd.concat()`, which constructs a MultiIndex dataframe of the outputs called `final`.

Comment: Hello, how can we do this in multiple for loop not within same line? ie different  instructions? My code is in following answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
file_path = '/home/iolie/Downloads/test/'
filenames = os.listdir(file_path)
prefixes = list(set(i.split('_')[0] for i in filenames))


for prefix in prefixes:
    for file in filenames: 
        if file.startswith(prefix):
            list_of_dfs= [ pd.concat( [pd.read_csv (os.path.join(file_path, file)], header=None ),ignore_index=True)]
            final=pd.concat(list_of_dfs)
```

Comment: Do not post this as an answer if it is producing an error. You need to make this an edit to your question.